# Java string split with repeating separator

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string formated like this:

```
String str = "AA.BBB..CC.DDDD...EE....F.G..H";
```

And I want to split this string by a dot with this as output:

```
AA
BBB
.CC
DDDD
.
EE
..
F
G
.H
```

`str.split("\\.")` of course did not work.

Comment: Why is there `two dots` in between E and F, in sequence? Shouldn't be those on two separate lines?

Comment: I think he wants every substring that starts and ends with a dot. Something like ".*." and, in case of multiple dots at the beginning of the substring, he takes the first one as separator and includes the others in the string.

Comment: @DanielaMogini.. In that case the output for `DDDD...EE....F` does not follow.

Comment: @Enroy.. Please specify on what basis you want the split. It is not clear from the output you posted.

Comment: One dot : handle it like split("\\.")
Two dots : take the first as separator, include 2nd dot in string
3+ dots : take outer dots as separator, and take everything between those as new string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
str.split("(?<!\\.)\\.|(?<=\\.\\.)\\.(?!\\.)")
```

The string should be split in these 2 cases:

- The `.` is not preceded by another `.`
- The `.` is not succeeded by `.`, and is preceded by 2 consecutive `.`.

Comment: +1 Was very near to it. But couldn't get the exact output. Was missing `(?<=\\.\\.)` in the 2nd part. :)